# How to sort on a text field with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
{
  "parent" : "some_id",
  "type" : "support",
  "metadata" : {
    "account_type" : "Regular",
    "subject" : "Test Subject",
    "user_name" : "John Doe",
    "origin" : "Origin",
    "description" : "TEST",
    "media" : [ ],
    "ticket_number" : "XXXX",
    "status" : "completed",
  },
  "create_time" : "2021-02-24T15:08:57.750Z",
  "entity_name" : "comment"
}
```

This is my demo data. and when I try to sort by **metadata.sort** for e.g. ->

```
GET comments-*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "type": "support"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [{
      "metadata.status": {
         "order": "desc"
       }
    }]
}
```

it says -> *Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [metadata.status] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.*

I am not sure how to achieve the same as I am very new to ESS. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You can only sort by fields of type "keyword" on string fields.

Elasticsearch dynamic mappings will create 2 fields if you dont set the mappings before sending docs.

In this case "status" , and "status.keyword".

So try with "metadata.status.keyword".

**TL;DR**

It is a good practice for fields you will not be doing full text search (like status flags) to only store the keyword version of the field.

To do that you have to set the mappings **before** indexing any document.

There is a trick:

1. Ingest Data

```
POST test_predipa/_doc
{
  "parent" : "some_id",
  "type" : "support",
  "metadata" : {
    "account_type" : "Regular",
    "subject" : "Test Subject",
    "user_name" : "John Doe",
    "origin" : "Origin",
    "description" : "TEST",
    "media" : [ ],
    "ticket_number" : "XXXX",
    "status" : "completed"
  },
  "create_time" : "2021-02-24T15:08:57.750Z",
  "entity_name" : "comment"
}
```

2. Get the autogenerated mappings

```
GET test_predipa/_mapping
```

3. Create a new empty index with the same mappings and modify as you want (on this case remove the text type field from metadata.status and let only the keyword one.

```
PUT test_predipa_new
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "create_time": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "entity_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "metadata": {
        "properties": {
          "account_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "origin": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "subject": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ticket_number": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "user_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "parent": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. Move the data from the old index to the new empty one

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "test_predipa"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "test_predipa_new"
  }
}
```

5. Run the sort query

```
GET test_predipa_new/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "support"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "metadata.status": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: one words:  just change "type" from "text" -> "keyword"

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, the issue is that `metadata.status` is of `text` type, which is not sortable ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html)). You can sort over a textual field if this is of a `keyword` type.

Please check the mapping of your index. Most probably, your index has default mapping ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html)), and a `keyword` sub-field is automatically assigned to every field with a string value.

TL;DR: try to run this query

```
GET comments-*/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "type": "support"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [{
      "metadata.status.keyword": {
         "order": "desc"
       }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi @glenacota thanks for your response. The above query you mentioned works for the values with specific indexes such as `GET comments-some-id/_search` but when using `GET comments-*/_search` i.e. for all indices it throws something like below
```
"reason" : "No mapping found for [metadata.status.keyword] in order to sort on"
```
not sure why but I have achieved the requirement using custom script like below
```
sort : {
      '_script': {
        'script': "doc['metadata.status.keyword'].value",
        'order': 'desc',
        'type': 'string'
      }
    }
```

Comment: The reason you were getting the error is that not all the indices matching the comments-* had a mapping for `metadata.status.keyword` (or no `metadata.status` field at all). I'm not sure why sorting by using the script didn't return you an error :sweat_smile:

Comment: Hey @PradiptaDey, was the question answered?

Comment: @glenacota -Will sorting be case-insensitive? How can I achieve a case-insensitive sort?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a sort on keyword or raw  based on the mapping given

```
GET comments-*/_search 
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "match": {
                "type": "support"
            }
        }]
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 50,
"sort": [{
  "metadata.status.keyword": {
     "order": "desc"
   }
}]
```

}